# When should I plant my grape?

Tags: grape-vine

I have a potted grape plant that I want to plant into the ground in Southern California (Mediterranean-desert).

What time of year should I do it, and what should I do regarding watering them then?

Comment: Where are you located? What is your climate?

Comment: Welcome to Gardening.SE. As michelle mentioned, we need more information to help you with this. If you could provide that and flag for reopening I'll be happy to do so.

Comment: @michelle now??

Comment: Thanks! I'm totally unfamiliar with your climate, but hopefully someone who isn't will chime in!

Answer (score 4):

Plant it during the coolest time of the year. That will let the roots get a good start before the warmer temps put stress on the plant. Grape vines - like my muscadine vines - like plenty of water. Also fertilize throughout the year. For a more in depth read, go to www.isons.com and look at their guides for grapes and muscadines.

Answer (score 4):

I did an experiment last season where I was replacing vines in part of my vineyard, over the course of the growing season (summer). These were vines in pots that had been propagated in my greenhouse, so I did not want to plant them too early in the season out of fear of any late frosts (these were growing vines and not dormant hard-cuttings). Regardless of when the vines were planted, I ensured each plant had been properly acclimated to the outside light levels. In this case, we're worried about too much UV exposure, as these vines have not produced the necessary 'sunscreen' components (e.g. carotenoids) within their leaves that aid in survival. Ever try bringing a houseplant outside for too long in the dead of summer? Not a good idea if you do not want burning to occur on your leaves. I usually took about a week to acclimate plants by bringing them outside for an hour or so the first day and then building upon that over the remaining days of the week.

I would caution against fertilizing too much beyond initial soil amendments, but that really all depends on the quality of your soil.